# OpenAI module keeps giving me an error when I try to use it with the API key

Tags: python, openai-api

I wanted to make a project in Python that required me to talk to ChatGPT to summarize articles. I imported the OpenAI API key. Unfortunately, it kept giving me this error even when I asked it to give me basic responses:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
        response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-002", prompt="Say 'This is a test.'.", temperature=0, max_tokens=6)
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
```

I tried waiting and then running again after a few minutes, but nothing happened.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.environ["openai"]
openai.organization = os.environ["organizationID"]
openai.Model.list()

response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-002", prompt="Say 'This is a test.'",     temperature=0, max_tokens=6)
print(response)
```

Comment: Do you understand the error ? It's pretty explicit : you/(people using the same APIkey) have used chatgpt too much regarding the offer you took.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I just thought I had a way not to have to pay, but it's alright.